# Verifying a Solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Verify that $$_2F_1(a,b;c:z) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \dfrac{(a)_n(b)_n}{(c)_n}\dfrac{z^n}{n!}$$
solves

$$z(1-z)\dfrac{d^2u}{dz^2} + [c-(a+b+1)]\dfrac{du}{dz}-abu=0?$$

by explicitly cranking through the motions of plugging it in.
I just can't get it to work out by directly differentiating, I just can't get it to work out - gets so so big, & just will not go to zero. I know this should be easy, but it just isn't working, it isn't true :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(a)_k(b)_k}{(c)_k}\frac{kx^{k-1}}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(a)_{k+1}(b)_{k+1}}{(c)_{k+1}}\frac{x^k}{k!}$

$ x\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(a)_{k+1}(b)_{k+1}}{(c)_{k+1}}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k!}$

$x\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(a)_{k+2}(b)_{k+2}}{(c)_{k+2}}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k!}$

$x^2\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(a)_{k+2}(b)_{k+2}}{(c)_{k+2}}\frac{x^{k+2}}{k!}$

\begin{align*}
&x(1-x)\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}+[c-(a+b+1)x]\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\\
=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(a)_{k+1}(b)_{k+1}x^{k+1}}{(c)_{k+1}k!}\left[\frac{(a+k+1)(b+k+1)}{(c+k+1)}-k+c\frac{(a+k+1)(b+k+1)}{(c+k+1)(k+1)}-(a+b+1)\right]+c\cdot ab/c\\
=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(a)_{k+1}(b)_{k+1}x^{k+1}}{(c)_{k+1}k!}\left[\frac{ab}{k+1}\right]+ab\\
=&ab~_2F_1(a,b;c:x)
\end{align*}

you may lose a $z$ after $(a+b+1)$

Comment: Why aren't you including a factor of $\tfrac{ab}{c}$ in front of $\tfrac{dF}{dx}$? For example the derivative as stated here includes it: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html ?

Comment: Except $c\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$, the other terms have no $x^0$ term, so I extract $ab/c$ outside the summation temporarily.